# Where are Azure SQL DB transaction logs located?

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-sql-database

Where can I find the transaction logs for a Azure SQL db?  I'm trying to debug why values in my db aren't what I expect them to be.

I apologize if this isn't the right *overflow for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Azure SQL DB does not expose the log.

Comment: wtf.  That's ridiculous.  Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: What do you do if it's full?

Answer (score 2):

Accessing to the transaction logs is not supported in SQL DB. However in V12 you may want to snapshot fn_dblog at regular intervals if you need TX log. The snapshot should happen before the log backup taken by Azure.